# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Play Framework 2.8.8 deployment issue with CheckProcfileForJavaApplication

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, scala, playframework, amazon-elb

Trying to deploy a Play Framework based Application using an ELB container

Recently it seems that AWS made changes to the way ELB works as we've done this before without issue.

The error we currently get is:

```
2021/12/14 23:00:15.705423 [INFO] Executing instruction: CheckProcfileForJavaApplication
2021/12/14 23:00:15.705468 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForJavaApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: there is no Procfile and no .jar file at root level of your source bundle 
2021/12/14 23:00:15.705474 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/12/14 23:00:15.705598 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1639522815,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

Now of course I wouldn't be here if this was the actual problem

```
# cd /var/app/staging/server-xxxxxxxxxxx/
# ls -l 
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 webapp webapp  135 Dec 14 20:39 Procfile
drwxr-xr-x 2 webapp webapp   82 Dec 14 22:21 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 webapp webapp  113 Dec 14 22:21 conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 webapp webapp 8192 Dec 14 22:21 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 webapp webapp   17 Dec 14 22:21 share
```

So Procfile exists

Hmmm is it valid however?

Let's check that out:

```
# cat Procfile 
web:  bin/server -v -J-Xms512M -J-Xmx2048m -J-server -Dhttp.port=5000 -Dhttps.port=8443 -Dconfig.resource=application.conf
```

Looks normal enough -- but does it actually work?

Short answer is yes -- if I copy and paste that command (minus the "web:" prefix of course) system comes up without any issues (ELB still fails to realize that though...)

I've tried a few variants of the command thinking that it might be related to yaml formatting of perhaps a tighter regex `^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+:\s*[^\s].*$` (source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

```
web:  bin/server
web:  ./bin/server
web: bin/server
web: ./bin/server
web:bin/server
web:./bin/server
```

No difference (both worked when manually started without or without the leading ./ btw)

Unsure how I move forward here?

How do we find what the real problem is so that we have fighting chance to fix it?

And yes -- the initial trace above is already the output of `eb-engine.log`

Using (in case this is relevant)

- Coretto Java 11
- Play 2.8.8
- Scala 2.13.6
- SBT 1.5.2

Will answer any relevant queries that help improve this question and any chance of resolving it. *Most Google searches I've dug through are related to other environments and are simply a missing Procfile...*

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that whomever wrote the ```CheckProcfileForJavaApplication``` routine literally checks for Java on that line in the Procifle. Of course Play Framework uses an intermediate launcher that subsequently calls Java. We have GitHub logs that show we've successfully used the above technique since at least mid 2015 so this is something "new" on AWS's part.

Comment: Also posted to Re: Post https://repost.aws/questions/QUSfLfdAlmThqC6dg35Y7JmQ/aws-elastic-beanstalk-play-framework-2-8-8-deployment-issue-with-check-procfile-for-java-application

Comment: Reading that initial error very literally: ```Error: there is no Procfile AND no .jar file at root level``` I created a ```dummy.jar``` and placed it at the root of the dist[ribution] folder just in case that got us past the goal post. Again no such luck...

Comment: I have worked out a work-around and will be publishing it after I've confirmed it runs stable through a number of normal ELB operations.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the following work-around to be able to use a standard (well slightly modified) Play Framework `dist` directly in an AWS ELB Java container

We start with the typical `sbt dist` process to create a zip "distribution" file

That file won't work in the format it is currently in (I've been researching and I will be asking specific questions to see if making it work directly might be possible) however it only takes a few small tweaks to get it to work

First Step: Modify `Procfile` (a file that you manually create and place in the project's `dist` directory) as follows:

```
   web: chmod 700 bin/server; bin/server -v -J-Xms512M -J-Xmx2048m -J-server -Dpidfile.path=/dev/null -Dhttp.port=5000 -Dconfig.resource=application.conf
```

Note the `chmod 700 bin/server;` that was the final secret sauce required to make this work! I was kinda shocked that it did work actually. I did not think that would get past the regex they use to parse the `Procfile`

As a zip file is permissions agnostic, once I finally got the elb install process to get past that first "missing jar" hurdle I noticed the permissions on `bin/server` were simply rw. The ec2 instance's  `/var/log/eb-engine.log` did not quite spell that out too clearly, however I confirmed that whenever I manually modified those permissions (on the ec2 instance) and then ran the `bin/server` command (to verify it) the Play server would start right away (however the elb container still failed to see it as a legitimate process and continued to report it as Status of no data, nor did it allow the load balancer to send it traffic so this "fix" was a real shot in the dark!)

Second step: Unzip that zip file and cd into the directory it created/assigned

```
   cd server-vxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
   touch placeholder.jar
```

The second dab of secret sauce is that the `placeholder.jar` file is simply a means to satisfy the `CheckProcfileForJavaApplication` which simply looks for the existence of any file named `*.jar` in the root of the bundled directory. If that file does not exist then the elb install script stops dead in it's tracks.

Note: You could simply place this empty `placeholder.jar` file in the Play `dist` folder if you prefer

Third Step: Create a new zip file `elb.zip`

```
   zip --exclude share/doc/api/\* -r elb.zip .
```

Now take `elb.zip` and upload it to an AWS ELB container and low and behold it (finally) springs to life!